# How to fetch Geo location of MQTT client devices when subscribing to a topic?

Tags: mqtt, broker

I am using MQTT protocol in real time data communication application,therefore I need to retrieve the client device location data and pass it to MQTT broker. Is there any available API to track client device Geo location in MQTT environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really isnt' clear what you are asking in the question but I'll try to cover all the options.

1. The device knows it's own location and you want to publish this information on a topic. Assuming the device has a GPS receiver (or some other way to determine it's own location e.g. data from a cellular network) then it's simply a case of building a message with a payload including the location data in what ever format you want
2. You are trying to determine the location of the client purely from it's connection to the broker. The broker will know the client's IP address so in theory it could use a IP Geolocation API to give an estimate of the devices location. There are no standard brokers with this capability so you would have to build your own. Also in most cellular environments the devices sit behind NAT gateways so you would only be able to locate the gateway not the end device.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hardillb, I will give a try on what you said. :)